# How do I select text in span tag located inside a div tag using BeautifulSoup3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have this line of code:

```
scoreline_div = soup.find("div", { "class" : "score-line" })
```

It selects a div tag page on the page, this is what it looks like:

```
<div class="score-line"><span class="home-team team team-900">South Africa</span><span class="score">27 - 27</span><span class="away-team team team-100">Australia</span></div>
```

How do I select the text of the first and third `span` (South Africa , Australia) ? Also, the classes of the span tag changes, so can I do it without searching it's `class`, and instead of selecting the first & third span?

Comment: why not access those spans by their positions?

Comment: how? Do you mean by typing `scoreline_div.span[0]`? It doesn't work, gives me an error

Comment: easy with `nth-of-type` selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=tag#find-all) method and get the list of spans:

```
scoreline_div = soup.find("div", { "class" : "score-line" })
spans = scoreline_div.find_all('span')
# spans[0].text should return 'South Africa'
# spans[2].text should return 'Australia'
```

Answer (score 2):

One-line solution:

```
s1,s2 = soup.find("div", { "class" : "score-line" }).select('span:nth-of-type(1),span:nth-of-type(3)')
print(s1.text, s2.text)
```

The output:

```
South Africa Australia
```